# What lies beneath the Maldives?

Tags: bedrock

What kind of underlying material are atolls like the Maldives built upon? Is there bedrock down there, or is it just sand and coral?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoll) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_the_Maldives) Wikipedia page? I don't have the knowledge to write an answer but would go there first